# Querying for friends and friends of friends optimization

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, laravel, optimization

I need to run a query for getting all friend ids and their friends' ids on a pivot table.

The table has two columns (that are relevant to this question), the requester id and accepter id.

To grab all friends of a user I must get all rows where `accepter_id == currentUserId` AND where `requester_id == currentUserId` since the current user can be the requester or accepter.

#### The problem:

To get all friends of friends' ids, I need to run a query for each of the current users friends' ids (where `accepter_id == currentUsersFriendId` AND where `requester_id == currentUsersFriendId`).

Many times the amount of queries exceed 200 (depending on the number of the current user's friends). When I benchmark it I consistently get around 2.2 to 2.7 seconds to finish getting friends and friends of friends. Obviously this takes too long.

#### The question:

What can I do to lower the time it takes to finish this query?

**Note:** I am using Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

#### Update

For the table, I'm using Laravel Schema builder (and I'm not an sql expert). So what I can show you is the php code representation of the create table statement. Here is the Laravel docs for the Schema builder: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema. Hopefully that can help?

```
Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('requester_id', false, true);
        $table->integer('accepter_id', false, true);
        $table->tinyInteger('status');

        $table->unique(['requester_id', 'accepter_id']);

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

Here are the select statements for grabbing friends. Notice I'm running a separate query for `where requester_id = userId` and `where accepter_id = userId`. Couldn't figure out how to combine the two together so I ran separate queries and combined them.

```
select `requester_id` from `friends` where `accepter_id` = ? and `status` = ?
select `accepter_id` from `friends` where `requester_id` = ? and `status` = ?
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on those columns?

Comment: I have a composite unique key for requester and accepter id.

Comment: I'd try putting an index on those two columns; the 2.2 to 2.7 is if you execute the query directly in the DB, right?

Comment: A unique key is an index, I believe? And I'm not sure what you mean by your second question. Do you mean am I directly communicating with the database instead of using the php code representation of a database query?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and show us the `SELECT` you are using.

Comment: @RickJames updated. Hopefully that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate compound indexes:

```
INDEX(requester_id, status, accepter_id)
INDEX(accepter_id, status, requester_id)
```

Then this UNION will run a lot faster:

```
( select `requester_id` from `friends` where `accepter_id` = ? and `status` = ? )
UNION ALL
( select `accepter_id` from `friends` where `requester_id` = ? and `status` = ? )
```

If that returns duplicates from those two SELECTs, and you need to de-dup the list, then use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION ALL`.

Comment: No advantage to say UNIQUE instead of simply INDEX.  On the other hand, why have `id` if this would work:  `PRIMARY INDEX(requerster_id, accepter_id)`?

Comment: Theres conventions in the Laravel framework and having an id primary key makes things much simpler. Anyways i'm implementing your solution, i will get back to you asap

Comment: Sorry it took so long, I did some benchmarking after messing around a bit. I dropped average time from 2.4 seconds to 1.4 (62% of the time taken). But I went a step further and dropped the ORM altogether and used PDO. That dropped it down to 0.6 seconds on average, which took a quarter of the time compared to the original query. I'm not too sure what effect the second index had on the query though I didn't make separate test cases for those.

Comment: Ah, another example of how 3rd party software gets in the way -- especially for performance.  Which is easier to code in -- ORM or PDO?

Comment: Of course the ORM (much easier), its the reason I use it.